# Does react native support base64 encoded images?

Tags: react-native

Does react native support base 64 encoded images?

I tried:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,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'}} style={styles.image}/>
```

but it didn't work.  Am I just doing is wrong or is it not supported?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: for react native web that same image not loaded am geting multiple images base64 from api

Comment: var array1 = ['./img1', './img2', './img3'];

array1.forEach(e =>{ 
 // console.log(`require(${e}`) 
  array1=`require(${e})`;
console.log(array1) 
  
  
});

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I think Ramsay is wrong, react native have a fully support on base64 image.
I found this

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html
```

this is a official example of how to create a iOS TabBarController, and they use a base64 image as one of the TabBar's icon.

I think you did not specify the `width` and the `height` in the `style` property of the `<Image/>`.

I tried to use your base64 image in my React Native Playground, and it works.

[image: demo]

Usage

```
var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
```

and use in this way

```
<Image style={{width: 100, height: 50, resizeMode: Image.resizeMode.contain, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}} source={{uri: base64Icon}}/>
```

Comment: However it doesn't support base64 svg, which would be really great

Comment: Is using base64 images a good idea? Surely it would greatly impact the performance of the diffing algorithm.

Comment: Still no luck for me, the same code that works for me on webplayer fails to render the image on my simulator.

Comment: need to add sub property, like  isStatic: true, example <Image source={{uri: base64Icon, isStatic: true}}/>

Comment: @Hoffmann if the base64 image prop is wrapped in an object the diffing will never be comparing the base64 string itself which would avoid this issue

Answer (score 29):

**Yes it is supporting.**

Try below 
It is tested in iOS and below version 
 **"react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.2",**

```
const base64Image = '...';
<Image source={{uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Image}`}} />
```

If still not working. check type of image i.e. jpeg, png etc.

Hope this help :)

Comment: <Image source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`}}
style={{ flex: 0.2,width:55, height:55, resizeMode: 'contain' }} /> for web working if am place dynamic base64 for gmail appicon or any for web not working

Answer (score 5):

```
 <Image
     source={{
        uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.barcodeImage}`,
     }}
     style={{height: 200, width: 250}}
 />
```

> notice : **add style in image**

Answer (score 3):

If you have a problem that the image does not appear, try to save the base64 of the image in a state and then use it

```
const [base64Image, setBase64Image] = useState<string>(BASE64DATA)

//... your code

<Image
    source={{
        uri: `data:image/jpg;base64,${base64Image}`
    }}
    resizeMode="cover"
    style={styles.profilePicture}
/>
```

IMPORTANT: furthemore check if the "jpg" in URI is same that your image extension

Answer (score 1):

```
   <Image
        style={{widht:"20" , height:"20%"}}
        source={{
          uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Hello, it would be better to add some explanations instead of just adding the code.

Comment: as you like, you might be getting encoded image data from a REST API call. You can use the 'data:' URI scheme to use these images. Same as for network resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image.
I hope you understand this time.

Comment: but if after all these explications, you don't understand,
you can check this https://reactnative.dev/docs/images
and this https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/convert+base64+to+image+in+react+native.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is supported. Unless the URL contains "http" or "https", it's considered a "static" image. Picking through the code, the instantiation of the final image boils down to:

```
if ([path isAbsolutePath]) {
  image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
} else {
  image = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
  if (!image) {
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:nil]];
  }
}
```

Step by step:

1. If the URL is an absolute path, load it as a file
2. Else if the image is cached (imageNamed), load that
3. Else if the image is a relative path, load it from the app bundle

Obviously none of that relates to base64. I've created a pull request for this feature which you can view here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/576

Comment: Thanks.  I think this could be really useful because it will allow the use of js libraries that generate base64 images.  For example, I'm currently wanting to generate a simple graph.