# React Native unable to display images as base64 'No suitable image URL loader found'

Tags: react-native

[image: Here is the error in console]

And here is the code I'm running. It loads fine if I use a image path.

```
var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
<Image source={{uri: base64Icon}} style={styles.thumbnail}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, looks right, double check that you're string is valid base64? when I tried to [decode](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Decode/), I got an error. could be the tool though.

and you need to set with and height of the image. since you didn't show your styles, not sure if you've done so.

this should work...

```
var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

<Image 
     style={{width: 100, height: 50,
     resizeMode: 'contain', 
     borderWidth: 1, 
     borderColor: 'red'}} 
     source={{uri: base64Icon}}
     />
```

[ref SOF for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380265/does-react-native-support-base64-encoded-images)

Comment: I still get the same error. Is it possible my react-native version is out of date? How can I check? (Other than running npm install and looking at package.json)

Comment: you can check which version of react native you're using by going into the node_modules/react-native/package.json file. If you've tried upgrading this project from a previous version at some point, I've noticed that upgrades don't always go smoothly. In such cases, I've created a fresh project `react-native init someproj` and rebuilt the project.

Comment: When I use data field instead ("source={{data: base64Icon}}") I do not get the error anymore, but the image still does not render. Does it matter which to use?

Comment: I found this related PR, but I'm not clear whether it's been merged into core or not. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/576

to answer your question, you should be using uri for sure. According to that PR, it also looks as though you need to add isStatic: true as in `source={{uri: base64Icon, isStatic: true}}` but I setup an example at rnplay and get the same error. So, I'm thinking that the above PR never made it into a release and has yet to be implemented. https://rnplay.org/apps/PAj27w

Comment: Also worth looking at is this example, which uses base64 as input to a TabBarIOS Icon https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html

Comment: I think this may have something to do with a bug related to borderWidth. When I remove borderWidth, I don't get an error. You can follow the conversation here... https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/576#issuecomment-167391811

Comment: Thanks for the gh link.