# How to decompress the image in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-image

I want to compress the image before saving it in database add decompress the image before displaying. I compress the image using 'react-native-image-resizer' and i got base64.
How can i decompress the image to get the original quality image?

Comment: Do you mean using base64 as image source ? [Base64 as Img Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380265/does-react-native-support-base64-encoded-images)

Comment: yes base64 format as image source