# Converts the text into a bitmap image

Tags: javascript, react-native, raster, thermal-printer

I am trying to build an iOS app that uses my thermal printer. I am using react-native, and the [react-native sdk](https://github.com/star-micronics/react-native-star-io10) that is supplied for the printer. I have a star TSP100IIIBi printer. It only accepts raster images as print commands. I would like to be able to print arbitrary strings of text to the printer, but to do so I need them to be encoded into an image.

For example, I would like to printer a some string key value pairs:

```
price: $43.23
user id: 4350
```

I would need to draw an image with these strings.

Is there way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i get your question right, here I found a website that will encode your image to string

Try this website https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/

Comment: I need to generate an image that is drawn with my strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33448478/17368959 I saw this revilement to you