# base64 images sometimes don't load in react native

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native, symfony

I'm trying to load a base64 image from my backend api, however I've reloaded my code a few times without changing anything, and sometimes it works just fine but most of the time it doesn't

enter code here

my code :

```
const [image, setImage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://example:8000/api/auth/return_picture/image',{
            method: 'GET'})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                setImage(responseJson.uri);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Image
                source={{uri: image ? `data:image/jpg;base64,${image}` : "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/09/f0/84/09f084cd8a8093ea5738a3ab75c210df.jpg"}}
                style={styles.avatar}/>
        </View>
    );
```

backend (php) :

```
/**
     * @Route("/return_picture/{image}", name="return_picture", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function return_picture(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request, $image): Response
    {

        $file = "uploads/profile_pictures/" . $image . ".jpg";
        $test = file_get_contents($file);


        return $this->json([
           "uri" => base64_encode($test)
        ]);
    }
```

sometimes it shows the proper image that i want to display :
[properly working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4JG1.png)

sometimes it only loads halfway : [halfway there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1k56.png)

sometimes it doesn't work at all and doesn't even show the default picture : [not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAD0K.png)

sometimes it shows the [default picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5h39.png) and the console shows an error message that says  **JSON Parse error: Expected '}'** (this happens most of the time)

any help would be much appreciated c-: !

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380265/does-react-native-support-base64-encoded-images

Comment: Thank you for your response ! i've tried fixing things here and there from the link you sent, but it didn't work for me, i'm suspecting the issue might be from the emulator

Comment: Try your code in expo snack. I tried running code in expo snack and it worked for me. You can verify it this way whether it is a problem with emulator or not

Comment: Sounds like the backend truncates the response randomly. Try using another image hosted somewhere else to test. If it works then the problem is in the backend.