React Native App: Images not loading when requested from server
In the application I am making, the images collected from the server are in Base64 to work with React instead of local file paths. I am trying to load them in this code onto the application however it doesn't seem to work.
There seems to be a delay when loading from server to front-end but I can't see a way to work around this. When it is loaded, no images appear and when they do, they don't load in the stylings.
For each patient ID there are 12 images. One at a time, the array from the server should show the Patient ID and the 12 images, however the 12 images should be split into 3 lots of 4x4 image galleries, using the left and right arrows to navigate between the 12. Moving onto the next patient id once the user has selected the correct rating...
const [patientData, setPatientData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRandomPatients();
  }, []);

  const fetchRandomPatients = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.0.14:3000/random-patients10`);
      if (response.ok) {
        const { patientData } = await response.json();
        setPatientData(patientData);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch random patients:", response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching random patients:", error);
    }
  };
 const handleArrowClick = (direction) => {
        if (direction === "prev") {
          setCurrentGallery((prev) => (prev === 0 ? patientData.length - 1 : prev - 1));
        } else {
          setCurrentGallery((prev) => (prev === patientData.length - 1 ? 0 : prev + 1));
        }
      };
<View style={styles.galleryContainer}>
        {patientData[currentGallery]?.images.map((image, index) => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => handleImageClick(index)}>
            <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={[styles.image, { transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }] }]} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.arrows}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleArrowClick("prev")} style={styles.arrowLeft}>
        <FontAwesome5 name="arrow-left" size={24} color="white" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleArrowClick("next")} style={[styles.arrowRight, { right: 0 }]}>
        <FontAwesome5 name="arrow-right" size={24} color="white" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>


The server code looks like:
app.get("/random-patients10", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const patients = await Patient.aggregate([
            { $match: { lesion_GS: { $ne: "" } } },
            { $sample: { size: 10 } },
            { $limit: 10 }
        ]);

        if (patients.length < 10) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Not enough valid patients found" });
        }

        const patientIds = patients.map(patient => patient.patient_id);

        const patientDataPromises = patientIds.map(async patientId => {
            try {
                const images = await Image.findOne({ patient_id: patientId });

                if (!images) {
                    throw new Error(`No images found for patient ${patientId}`);
                }

                const filePaths = [];

                // Collect file paths from 'highest', 'lowest', and 'middle' arrays if they exist
                if (images.highest) {
                    images.highest.forEach(image => {
                        const base64Image = fs.readFileSync(image.file_path, { encoding: 'base64' });
                        filePaths.push(`data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`);
                    });
                }
                if (images.lowest) {
                    images.lowest.forEach(image => {
                        const base64Image = fs.readFileSync(image.file_path, { encoding: 'base64' });
                        filePaths.push(`data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`);
                    });
                }
                if (images.middle) {
                    images.middle.forEach(image => {

                        const base64Image = fs.readFileSync(image.file_path, { encoding: 'base64' });
                        filePaths.push(`data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`);
                    
                    });
                }

                return { patientId, images: filePaths };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error fetching images for patient ${patientId}: `, error);
                return { patientId, images: [] };
            }
        });

When the code is run this is the printed: .../g91wv9/sM76P1T//w7Y839dDHf8H+q1//u9vQfM+ocZ9G8zadY/jMe/r/Ws/8UYzfpva+G/wwDB/wf/k+Enyqj95MPpp0vNfyj98B+G3AP8/4Hu/UQv/f/6jeff0U4NAACgR3j/Xe6s/wTPv6OqeNK/HC//H99hZv1Df3z4r+//jZT0fyrM+h9Uw1n/pUXw39HmWf9lzP8r6jwLaGDP/5KC/78U4P/tIfpfUYL/vWH/78f6P4v7/Ue69eH/a2r+X5vOH4L/gfD/A8PlKshXU546AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"], "patientId": "10092"}]
I have tried many different solutions, including code such as :
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.0.189:3000/random-patients10");
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Data received from server:", data); 
        setPatientImages(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching patient images: ", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  if (patientImages && patientImages[0]) {
    const image1 = patientImages[0].images[0];
    //console.log("Img1", image1);
    const image2 = patientImages[0].images[1];
    //console.log("Img2", image2);
    const image3 = patientImages[0].images[2];
    //console.log("Img3", image3);
    const image4 = patientImages[0].images[3];
    //console.log("Img4", image4);
} else {
    console.log("Patient images data not available yet");
}
useEffect(() => {
  // Update current images when patient index changes
  if (patientImages && patientImages.length > 0) {
    const patient = patientImages[currentPatientIndex];
    setCurrentImages(patient.images);
  }
}, [currentPatientIndex, patientImages]);



If your images are in base64 format, you need to add data:image/png;base64, followed by your base64 string. Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33448478/8196025.
